GitVersion doesn't use the "label" string when on master
I've recently upgraded to GitVersion 6.0.x (due to various other issues) and now I can't seem to get my master builds to get versioned correctly. I want the master builds to be named "-alpha" and only any tagged builds to get the exact version of the next-version field.
This is my gitversion.yml:
# current development version which is first version of next release branched away from master
next-version: 6.4.0

# configuration for all branches
tag-prefix: '[vV]?'
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
mode: ContinuousDelivery
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled

branches:
  master:
    label: '-alpha'
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    is-main-branch: true

  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    regex: ^workitems?[/-](?<BranchName>.+)
    label: '--w.{BranchName}'
    source-branches: ['master']
    pre-release-weight: 0
    
  pull-request:
    regex: (pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    label: -pr
    source-branches: ['master']

  # Official product releases
  release:
    regex: releases/[Vv]
    label: beta
    # Increment patch version after a release
    increment: Patch
    source-branches: ['master']

If I'm on a feature branch, everything seems to work, but when I'm on master, this is the output:
{
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "6.4.0.48990",
  "AssemblySemVer": "6.4.0.48990",
  "BranchName": "master",
  "BuildMetaData": null,
  "CommitDate": "2024-11-05",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 48990,
  "EscapedBranchName": "master",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "Branch.master.Sha.3edf09c0a1683a97b79b2380bXXXX",
  "FullSemVer": "6.4.0-48990",
  "InformationalVersion": "6.4.0-48990+Branch.master.Sha.3edf09c0a1683a97b79b2380b5XXX",
  "Major": 6,
  "MajorMinorPatch": "6.4.0",
  "Minor": 4,
  "Patch": 0,
  "PreReleaseLabel": "",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseNumber": 48990,
  "PreReleaseTag": "48990",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "-48990",
  "SemVer": "6.4.0-48990",
  "Sha": "3edf09c0a1683a97b79b2380b5cdacXXXXXX",
  "ShortSha": "3edf09c",
  "UncommittedChanges": 1,
  "VersionSourceSha": "",
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 103990
}


with the 5.X version of gitversion the output was like:
  "Major":6,
  "Minor":4,
  "Patch":0,
  "PreReleaseTag":"alpha.13161",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"-alpha.13161",
  "PreReleaseLabel":"alpha",
  "PreReleaseNumber":13161,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber":68161,
  "BuildMetaData":"",
  "BuildMetaDataPadded":"",
  "FullBuildMetaData":"Branch.master.Sha.2acac930ea679651600c0ab55cXXXXXXX",
  "MajorMinorPatch":"6.4.0",
  "SemVer":"6.4.0-alpha.13161",
  "LegacySemVer":"6.4.0-alpha13161",
  "LegacySemVerPadded":"6.4.0-alpha0013161",
  "AssemblySemVer":"6.4.0.13161",
  "AssemblySemFileVer":"6.4.0.13161",
  "FullSemVer":"6.4.0-alpha.13161",
  "InformationalVersion":"6.4.0-alpha.13161+Branch.master.Sha.2acac930ea679651600c0ab55c5XXXXXXXX",
  "BranchName":"master",
  "Sha":"2acac930ea679651600c0ab55c53bXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ShortSha":"2acac93",
  "NuGetVersionV2":"6.4.0-alpha0013161",
  "NuGetVersion":"6.4.0-alpha0013161",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2":"alpha13161",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag":"alpha13161",
  "VersionSourceSha":"16f71543433b202773b49d6d5a7dbXXXXXXXXX",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":13161,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0013161",
  "CommitDate":"2024-10-24"

Relevant part of the old yml file:
# current development version which is first version of next release branched away from master
next-version: 6.4.0

# configuration for all branches
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
mode: ContinuousDeployment
legacy-semver-padding: 7
build-metadata-padding: 7
commits-since-version-source-padding: 7
commit-message-incrementing: Disabled

branches:
  master:
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    tag: alpha

  feature:
    regex: workitems?[/-]
    tag: --w.{BranchName}
    source-branches: ['master']

How do I get gitversion 6.0.X to do the same as the previous version for the master branch? Namely the PreRelaseLabel appears to be always empty.

I found the issue. When running gitversion /showconfig it was visible that there was a default main branch included in the configuration which took precedence over the manually defined master branch. And thus the setting for the master branch where never applied. Changing the yml to
branches:
  main:
    label: 'alpha'
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    is-main-branch: true

fixed the issue.
